# IPad CSS Issue - Site Renders correctly on Chrome,Firefox and IE for desktop

Tags: ipad, html, css

I am at a loss about this site. The search button moves to the right of the box and the mega menu background does not show plus the menu items are jumbled up. The site link is below:

http://speedyapplication.com/corporate60sunglowred/HOME/tabid/4295/Default.aspx

What could be going on here? Please help.

Comment: not getting the downvote resn ? why people downvote the question and dont leave comment how  OP know the resn of downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width for dnn_dnnSearch_txtSearchNew is set to 90% which doesn't seem to work as intended. Try setting something like 165px.

Safari, iPhone and iPad browsers don't have a persistent scroll bar, so page widths don't take them in to account, whereas other browsers do. Also try Safari for the desktop. With Safari for Mac you I can see the search button issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try Safari for Windows. Also any idea why the menu background is not showing up and the menu items are all jumbled up?

Comment: I can see you're using 
-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F9F9F9 0%, #C1BFBF 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent

Which won't work. You need background: -webkit-linear-gradient(aqua, white)   etc. 

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html

Comment: That's right. iPad is a webkit browser. You're just using the Mozilla prefix.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Resolved the search button issue. Still need help with the menu items. When you hover over the about menu on iPad the menu items are all jumbled up.